# async_upload.php 500 Error when Uploading larger files with slow internet connection and latency

Tags: uploads, 500-internal-error, plupload

my page runs on a local corporate network on a Windows 2016 server running IIS 10.
PHP 7.1
WordPress 5.3

The page is used as a video platform. Videos up to 2GB can be uploaded. From our locations on the same network (upload speed 25-50Mbps) the upload works without any problems. 
The corresponding parameters in IIS, php.ini and wp-config.php are set correctly. The timeouts on the server and the proxies are set to 2 hrs.

The problem is:

Uploads >300MB will not complete from other locations over WAN.
The connection corresponds to approx. 4Mbps uploadspeed with 130ms latency. If I simulate the upload in Chrome with these settings, I will end up with a 500 error of async-upload.php. How can I optimize the page for slow connections and latency?

I am grateful for hints!

Chrome Network Log:

Request URL: https://XXX.intra.net/wp-admin/async-upload.php
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address: 53.26.9.187:3128
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Connection: close
Content-Length: 1208
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Mon, 02 Dec 2019 13:40:45 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: XXX
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 518192654
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=—-WebKitFormBoundaryBYhwvYy8edwoTGJh
Cookie: wordpress_sec_8e85a50d55023e68686338106663e49d=mwerbro%7C1575444406%7CmsjSnLM6HQzCeaOxjCP7aKQvqApaGGc45mHp5xiJusy%7C1632275c6b5a9f9e15fbbac0896441e90e82a263ad537b7f64fa39488e5cc72b; vchideactivationmsg_vc11=6.0.5; catAccCookies=1; wp-settings-time-134=1575035781; wp-settings-134=libraryContent%3Dbrowse%26editor%3Dhtml%26edit_element_vcUIPanelWidth%3D649%26edit_element_vcUIPanelLeft%3D923px%26edit_element_vcUIPanelTop%3D74px%26posts_list_mode%3Dlist; wordpress_logged_in_8e85a50d55023e68686338106663e49d=mwerbro%7C1575444406%7CmsjSnLM6HQzCeaOxjCP7aKQvqApaGGc45mHp5xiJusy%7Cecc5ac52a0f081c9ec834ca0a2036b2bf44482f02a5f20e1184f7fa585053bc3; wp-wpml_current_admin_language_d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e=de; _pk_ref.275.97ea=%5B%22%22%2C%22%22%2C1575288534%2C%22https%3A%2F%2Fsocial.intra.corpintra.net%2Finbox%22%5D; _pk_ses.275.97ea=1; wp-wpml_current_language=de; _pk_id.275.97ea=4c61b23bd9343dc7.1571816982.119.1575293156.1575288534.; ADRUM=s=1575293617793&r=https%3A%2F%2Fsocial.intra.corpintra.net%2Flogin.jspa%3F-72025792
Host: XXX.intra.net
Origin: https://XXX.intra.net
Referer: https://XXX.intra.net/wp-admin/media-new.php
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36
name: C0008.MP4
post_id: 0
_wpnonce: 523ff9aa48
type:
tab:
short: 1
async-upload: (binary)

Comment: A 500 error is just your servers way of saying "something went wrong! See the error logs to find out what it is", you'll need to check your PHP error logs to find out what the actual problem is

Comment: Hi Tom, i already checked the logs: there is always something like this: 2019-12-03 12:25:23 53.71.236.51 POST /wp-admin/async-upload.php - 80 - 53.71.100.242 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/77.0.3865.120+Safari/537.36 https://xxx.intra.net/wp-admin/media-new.php 500 0 995 329640 The Problem is, that the error only appears, when i reduce the upload speed - with full bandswith the uploads up to 2GB always workin fine

Comment: That doesn't look like a PHP error log message, that's an Nginx/Apache access log, you need to check the PHP error log. If you don't have one or  can't find it your host  can enable/locate it for you. If the upload speed is what's determining the problem then I suspect this isn't really a WP issue but either a network or PHP configuration issue. Have you confirmed your increases to the PHP time limit have actually taken effect?

Comment: The page runs, as described, on a Windows server with IIS. In fact, there was still a timeout for fastCGI not set correctly. It works now.

Comment: if it runs on IIS but not Apache, then clearly the WordPress/PHP part is not to blame and it's the server. You don't need WordPress help and expertise, you need Apache help. Aside from that, you didn't check the PHP error logs :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tom, it seems that you don´t understand. The issue is fixed now. When i checked my PHP error logs, i figured out, that in my fastcgi config a to short Timeout was set.